# Добавление пробелов до нужной длины

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно добавить в конец строки неопределённое количество пробелов так, чтобы длины строки была равно заданному значению. Например, я хочу, чтобы длина результирующей строки была 20 символов, и в случае, если длина входной строки меньше, то к ней нужно добавить пробелов до нужной длины.

Например, если входная строка `'мама мыла раму'` и нужная длина 20, то мне нужна функция вроде

```
SELECT FUNCTION('мама мыла раму', 20, ' ');
```

которая в результате выведет `'мама мыла раму      '`. Есть ли такая функция в MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT RPAD('мама мыла раму', 20, ' ');
```

Если исходная строка длиннее, чем указанное число символов, она будет обрезана, так что будьте внимательны.
[Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad).